# Slow boot on Ubuntu 16.04 ... issue with pam_kwallet5.so

Tags: boot, 16.04, lightdm, pam, kwallet

I'm trying to find the cause of my slow boot time and so I checked the log file and found this from the time of restart:

```
Feb  4 00:54:17 blackbird3460 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb  4 00:54:17 blackbird3460 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Feb  4 00:54:17 blackbird3460 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb  4 00:54:17 blackbird3460 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Feb  4 00:54:17 blackbird3460 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
```

What is that?

Comment: Please format the question

Comment: I formatted the question, so can you give a thumbs up now?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1309535)
the issue with pam_kwallet5.so occurs because you don't have kwallet installed (it's optional, and not necessary). From my own experience, it is possible to have this annoying and misleading error message without having a slow boot problem.

I think you need to look elsewhere for the cause of your slow boot problem. Try `systemd-analyze blame` or any other boot processes analyzers in order to find the real cause of your slow boot problem.